# Navigate to page on start in .NET Maui app

Tags: maui, app-shell

Seems like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find a simple answer. Essentially I want to choose which page in the app to start on based on some stored state. I added a GoToAsync call in the AppShell constructor, but this didn't work--which makes sense because the AppShell hasn't been fully constructed yet.

I found this answer, but it feels like it kind of skirts around the issue:

[Maui AppShell - Navigate on Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488406/maui-appshell-navigate-on-open)

Where is the best place to inject some code that will run once on startup and can successfully navigate a .NET Maui app to a chosen page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing around with overrides, it seems like overriding `Application.OnStart` works! `Shell.Current` is set at this point and navigation works.

Here's additional code that allows for asynchronous initialization and uses a Loading Page until the initialization is complete:

```
using MyApp.Services;
using MyApp.UI;

namespace MyApp;

public partial class App : Application
{
    ConfigurationProviderService m_configProvider;

    public App(ConfigurationProviderService configProvider)
    {
        m_configProvider = configProvider;

        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new LoadingPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        var task = InitAsync();

        task.ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                MainPage = new AppShell();

                // Choose navigation depending on init
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync(...);
            });
        });

        base.OnStart();
    }

    private async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await m_configProvider.InitAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your aproach, and I always got the following exception:
System.Exception: 'Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported. Try prefixing your uri with ///: ///main'

Comment: @Wasyster try "///main" or "///" + nameof(main) whatever way you're doing it.

Comment: @Wasyster I also found tha tre-ordering the "<ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:LoginPage}"
        Route="LoginPage" />" entries in AppShell.xaml effectively sets the first page to LoginPage if that's what's first listed.  This means you don't need any of the above code to start out statically on a certain page.   You then, once the user hits login, switch the page to your normal "///" + nameof(MainPage).   Also note that if you were experience things breaking with switching some other way, this should fix that.  Because it's the most natural.  Now my dark/light works